# Is .p12 certificate for Apple Push Notification doesn't need APNs Auth Key?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, app-store

I read this article https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-get-an-apple-push-notification-service-certificate-as-a-p12-e124c64093c0 stating how to create .p12 certificate for Push Notification.

It doesn't involve generate APNs Key as shown in diagram below. Is it true the .p12 doesn't need any APNs key at all?

[image]

Comment: you use firebase cloud messaging for push notification??

Comment: I have used both firebase as well as UrbanAirship. I assume both of them are using .p12. For blaze, I assume that's using .p8 (which then only the APNs Auth Key is required). Right?

Comment: i think so, otherwise you should check that your APNs Auth Key generation maximum limit will reached or not.